# Is there a faster (more concise) way to set many parameters for PreparedStatements in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

While working with JDBC I ran into a table that has a lot of columns. I was wondering if it was possible to set parameters in Prepared Statements in a faster and maybe mor efficient way than the one below (maybe implementing an "ad hoc" method).

```
public void create(FilmBean film) {
    try {
        String queryString = "Insert INTO film(film_id, title, description, release_year, language_id, original_language_id,"
                + " rental_duration, rental_rate, length, replacement_cost, rating, special_features, last_update) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)";
        connection = getConnection();
        ptmt = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
        ptmt.setInt(1, film.getFilmId());
        ptmt.setString(2, film.getFilmTitle());
        ptmt.setString(3, film.getDescription());
        ptmt.setInt(4, film.getReleaseYear());
        ptmt.setInt(5, film.getLanguageId());
        ptmt.setInt(6, film.getOriginalLanguageId());
        ptmt.setInt(7, film.getRentalDuration());
        ptmt.setFloat(8, film.getRentalRate());
        ptmt.setInt(9, film.getLength());
        ptmt.setFloat(10, film.getReplacementCost());
        ptmt.setString(11, film.getRating());
        ptmt.setString(12, film.getSpecialFeatures());
        ptmt.setTimestamp(13, film.getLastUpdate());
        ptmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Data Added Successfully");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ptmt != null)
                ptmt.close();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By "faster" are you actually looking for more concise code, or an execution-time performance improvement? I'd be surprised if setting the parameters was actually a bottleneck.

Comment: I meant concise, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: By just using plain JDBC, the answer is probably "no". However, you can use ORMs to work for you; this will entail more setup work at the beginning and a new learning curve to tackle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no more concise way to set parameters in JDBC itself. However, there are libraries that can simplify this for you. For example, Spring's `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate`, or you can switch to using an ORM like Hibernate.

As to faster, no there is nothing faster. Any other abstraction you use in Java will ultimately use the JDBC API, and will necessarily be slower than direct JDBC usage.